# Implement a "maintenance mode" in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How could you implement a site-wide "Maintenance mode" for your Asp.Net Core app?

Requirements:

- All controller requests respond with the same static "Maintenance mode" page
- You need to be able to flip a switch in the backend to turn maintenance mode on and off (so it has to happen at runtime)

My current best idea is an actionfilter on all controllers, where I check for the maintenance mode in code (bit in a database) and just return the maintenance mode page if maintenance mode is true.

Comment: An action filter would be okay, you could also use a custom middleware that skips routing altogether.

Comment: Do maintenance mode at the firewall. Otherwise, how are you going to test your system before you open it to the public?

Comment: @JohnWu I don't disagree that doing it further out is better, but I have a client that insists on having a button in their backend. And this is not to test before launch, this is a panic-button if the site contains something potentially illegal (they're in a heavily regulated market with lots of grey areas - fines are a real risk).

So while I agree with you, in this case I have to do it.

Comment: [Middleware Madness: Site Maintenance In ASP.NET Core](https://rimdev.io/middleware-madness-site-maintenance-in-aspnet-core/) // by Khalid Abuhakmeh and Bill Boga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that. You can use environment variable in your application, But that you must be need to be modified VariableName whenever you need to turn off maintenance.

```
"IIS Express (Staging)": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
  }
}
```

Look at above code is from launchSettings.json files. which contains set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as a Staging.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
       app.UseBrowserLink();
   }
   else
   {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Maintainance");
   }
}
```

Even you could also be change some content in your layout.cshtml page as per your environment variable.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<your-regular-css-files>" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<your-maintainance-css-files>" />
</environment>
```

But Here is your one requirement is that to, you should need to be able to change maintenance mode on backed side. In this scenario change JSON file ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value from your admin panel. I think this should be work fine.

Answer (score 4):

From the Microsoft docs, you can use the standard app_offline.htm mechanism:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#app_offlinehtm-2

Comment: That does not fulflll the requirement to be able to switch it on and off in the backend, unfortunately.

Comment: How do It for kestrel? @DvS

Comment: @KOMODO there doesn't seem to be any equivalent, but the aspnetcore team are considering the concept of a hot restart. You can check out their discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5937) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27270)

Answer (score 0):

As Pandurang Choudekar said, you can indicate whether maintenance mode is enabled or disabled through the settings file (appSettings) of each environment.

```
{
 "MaintenanceMode": {
    "IsEnabled": true
 }
}
```

Create a Middleware that will read this configuration and redirect to the default Maintenance page.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class MaintenanceMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MaintenanceMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _next = next;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (IsMaintenanceModeEnabled())
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/error/maintenance";
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }

    private bool IsMaintenanceModeEnabled()
    {
        var isEnabled = _configuration["MaintenanceMode:IsEnabled"];

        return isEnabled.ToLower() == "true";
    }
}

public class MaintenanceModeOptions
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure your Middleware in your project's Startup.cs file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.Configure<MaintenanceModeOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MaintenanceMode")); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<MaintenanceMiddleware>();
}
```

More details (with minor variations) can be obtained from this article: https://eekayonline.medium.com/how-to-implement-a-maintenance-mode-in-asp-net-core-f0348e852664